# How to get iteration count in cucumber?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I wanted to get iteration count in cucumber when we are executing feature file with multiple row from example in feature file.

Answer (score 0):

In the cucumber with .feature file! loop construct & count directly not possible.

You can do in your JAVA or Python